# How to use str_glue in data.table (environments question)

Tags: r, data.table, stringr

In a real life project I am trying to create a function to be used in data.table (j) which relies on string formatting using the str_glue function. I get an error related to environments.

What follows below is a trivial example (converting mpg to l/100km in the mtcars dataset) to highlight the behavior. My example might seem convoluted (e.g. a list holding only 1 element) but this is to better reflect my real-life problem which is of course more complex.

01 - Setting up the data.table and the list holding the conversion factor

```
conversion_rates = list(mpg_lkm = 282.5)
dt = as.data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames = "rn")
```

02 - Creating a function to calculate liters per 100km

```
mpg_to_lkm = function(mpg, cr) {
  cri = cr$mpg_lkm
  return(cri / mpg)
}
```

03 - using the function in j, by passing the column as the first argument, and the conversion rates from the global environment as the second

```
dt[, lkm := mpg_to_lkm(mpg, conversion_rates)] # passing conversion_rates works
head(dt)
```

So far so good. I seem to have established that you can pass arguments from the data.table scope and global scope without any problem.

04 - defining a function that will create a 'character' column which explains the formula

```
explain_formula = function(mpg, cr) {
  print(ls(envir = environment())) # proves that mpg & cr are available in my envir
  cri = cr$mpg_lkm
  result = paste("lkm obtained by dividing {cri} by", mpg) # curly brace notation      
  result = purrr::map_chr(result, stringr::str_glue) # str_glue is not vectorised so I use map
  return(result)
}
```

05 - testing my function shows that it runs smoothly

```
testcol = dt$mpg
result = explain_formula(testcol, conversion_rates)
result # --> output exactly as expected
```

06 - now trying it from j in data.table

```
dt[, cr := explain_formula(mpg, conversion_rates)]
```

throws error

```
 Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) : 
  object 'cri' not found
```

str_glue has as a default argument envir = parent.frame(). The parent frame of a function evaluation is the environment in which the function was called. In my case this has to be the environment of "explain_formula" right?

I have found out that 2 things work solve my issue:

- creating cri in the global environment -> not usefull for my real life problem
- passing .envir = environment() to str_glue -> this is my current solution

Can anyone explain me where my reasoning is bad? Why is '06' not giving the desired result?

Comment: does str_glue have an environment argument?

Comment: try passing the environment specifically, or using str_glue_data instead

Comment: This open issue is about `glue::glue()` not working in [tag:data.table]: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4879